# Found markup element with unexpected name 'Cascading AuthenticationState'

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I am getting this error on my App.razor:

> Found markup element with unexpected name
> 'CascadingAuthenticationState'. If this is intended to be a component,
> add a @using directive for it namespace

This is the code I am using

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

[image]

I am using Visual Studio 2019 preview and I can run the application but, why do I have the red line in the Cascading....?

Comment: That code by itself is OK, you are probaly using the wrong packages. Make sure you are up to date to the 3.0 released version. For an existing project, follow the update guidelines.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Could you please point out what package to install for that error?

Comment: But I now see the client-side tag. The App.razor you posted is for server-side.

Comment: but it is in the client side. Ever since last update, I couldn't run this anymore. on my last work, before this last update, i was able to make this run without issues.

Comment: The latest of what package Sir?

Comment: post the contents of your csproj. More specifically, the `ItemGroup` containing all the  `<PackageReference .. />`

Comment: Microsoft's dotnet repo has a related issue: https://github.com/dotnet/razor-tooling/issues/4590

Answer (score 42):

**Warning!**
The .vs folder contains all the data that VS gathered about the projects in your solution, the opened files, debug. You will lose all that!

Close Visual Studios and delete the .vs hidden folder in the root of your solution.

Start up your project and the error's will be gone.

Comment: This one worked for me. I was using LTS versions for packages so updates SHOULD not be needed!

Comment: I thought this solutions originally did not work, but it can apparently take a few minutes for VS to re-index the project dependencies and make the squiggles go away in some cases. This appears to have fixed my issue! Thank you!

Comment: this still works in 2023, VS2022 64 bit

Answer (score 22):

For me adding **both references** to _Imports.razor worked to solve same issue:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
```

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to also install the correct NuGet pages for this to work.

Comment: They were already present and still have the same issue. Deleting the .vs folder works for me.

Comment: Had this same issue for the new QuickGrid. I'm a very experienced developer, but the QuickGrid install guide didn't tell me I needed to do this so I didn't. And here I am :-) Just needed to add `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid` to _Imports.razor

Answer (score 6):

This issue went away for me after updating "Build Action" from "None" to "Content" for newly added razor component.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. Right Click Project
2. Manage Nuget Packages
3. Select "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor" which you have already installed.
4. Update with Latest stable version then...
5. **Update Latest preview again.**

[image]

Comment: I've had to do this twice now and twice this has helped me because it reminded me to check for NuGet updates, which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

For .NET 6

- Make sure `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization` NuGet package is installed
- Add `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization` to _*Imports.razor* file

Answer (score 3):

The solution which works for me is the following:

1. Rebuild Solution
2. Clean Solution
3. Close VS
4. Delete all bin/obj folders in the source
5. Open solution in VS
6. Rebuild Solution
7. Close and reopen the file inside of VS where the element is used (not always necessary)
8. Success, markdown element is found
9. Sometimes you have to do this procedure multiple times

Comment: Worked for me, thanks (I also deleted the .vs folder before doing what you said, not sure if that was necessary or not)!

Comment: In my case I did not have to delete the .vs folder.

Answer (score 2):

If I create a razor component as right click -> add new item -> razor component,
then everything is ok. But if I copy-paste an existing razor component and do further work on it, then it creates the above stated issue.

Comment: This is ultimately the one I have seen so you always have to restart your IDE to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an IntelliSense issue of the VisualStudio, see: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/770539/visual-studio-lost-intellisense-for-blazor-compone.html

Comment: I see similar issue with VS2022.  Blazor intellisense is pretty terrible.  The app compiles and runs flawlessly, but I consistently see warnings and ugly squiggly lines in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I found these entries about my "problem" component in my `.csproj` file. After deleting them (VS closed) and re-open the solution, the error has been gone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a MudBlazor component, in fact it did not see any MudBlazor component when you typed [Mud into the .razor file in the editor.

As far as I can tell, I was trying to use MudBlazor with .Net 8 and the latest version of MudBlazor has dependency listings for .Net 6 and .Net 7 but nothing listed for .Net 8

After downgrading my Target Framework to .Net 7 the MudBlazor components came back to life, strangely after switching back to .Net 8 they were still there.