# Found a markup element with unexpected Routes in Blazor Web App

Tags: blazor

We have the `App.razor` and `Routes.razor` files in the same root folder, but we are getting a warning in the `App.razor` file that it found a markup element with unexpected routes in Blazor web app.

Here is the our code for `App.razor`:

```
@inject IHostEnvironment Env

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Radzen.Blazor/css/standard-base.css">
    <script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="OD.Dax.UX.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)" />
</head>
<body>
 <Routes @rendermode="new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)" />

    @if (Env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        <text>
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text>
            An error has occurred. This app may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </text>
    }
    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can we resolve this warning? The funny thing is that the program runs!!!

Answer (score 0):

Followed the same procedure found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336875/found-markup-element-with-unexpected-name-cascading-authenticationstate?rq=2)

Warning! The .vs folder contains all the data that VS gathered about the projects in your solution, the opened files, debug. You will lose all that!

Close Visual Studios and delete the .vs hidden folder in the root of your solution.

Start up your project and the error's will be gone.